# How to start java swing timer from time when function were stoped in Java swing

Tags: java, swing, animation, timer

I need to stop animation wait a while, and be able to start from the time when it was stoped. Actually I can stop and start again but animation is still performed in background.

This part of code start/stop animation:

```
JButton btnAnimate = new JButton("Animate");
    btnAnimate.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            kanwa.animate(); 
            kanwa.buffer.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        }
    });
```

This function start/stop timer:

```
    void animate() { 
    start=System.nanoTime();
    if (timer.isRunning()) {
        timer.stop();
    }  else{

        timer.start();
    }
}
```

And this part of code inizialize and add figures to animation:

```
public void initialize() {
    int width = getWidth();
    int height = getHeight();

    image = createImage(width, height);
    buffer = (Graphics2D) image.getGraphics();
    buffer.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    device = (Graphics2D) getGraphics();
    device.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
}

void addFig() {
    Figura fig = (numer++ % 2 == 0) ? new Kwadrat(buffer, delay, getWidth(), getHeight())
            : new Elipsa(buffer, delay, getWidth(), getHeight());
    timer.addActionListener(fig);
    new Thread(fig).start();

    }
```

What in need to change to be able to start animation again from the time when it was stopped?

ps. It's a task and I must use java swing and timer.

Comment: If all you want to do is change the state of a Swing Timer (start or stop it) when a thread has been completed, then use a callback method with your thread, such as via a PropertyChangeListener. If this isn't what you're trying to do or does not solve your problem, then please clarify your question including by creating and posting a valid [mcve], a very small compilable and runnable program that demonstrates your problem for us.

Comment: ok thanks I'll try it

Comment: A `Timer` is used to generate an event. When the event is fired you do your animation. So when you stop the `Timer` the animation stops automatically. There is no need for a Thread.

Comment: Yes it stop but dont start from the moment when stoped. It's link to github repo with code you can test it if you want: https://github.com/w-gasiewicz/JP_lab6